# RabbitMQ security : how to prevent consumer from creating an exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an fanout exchange (named : test_exchange) for which I allow users to dynamically create queues.  In order to prevent them to create whatever they want I have restricted their access this way:

- Configure : test_exchange.*
- Write : test_exchange.*
- Read : test_exchange.*

When creating a queue to bind to the exchange, they have to use the following naming convention : test_exchange.(some guid), for example : test_exchange.hjLgS6JRTzbuQ48FyWFIZQ

This works fine.  Except that they can also create exchanges if they respect the naming convention.

According to [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html)

- QueueDeclare : needs the configure rights
- QueueBind : needs the write rights

The problem is that to create an exchange you need the same configure rights.

What could be the solution to allow a consumer to only create a queue, and bind it to a specific exchange ?

And no other access rights?